# match url that doesnt contain asp, apsx, css, htm.html,jpg

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Q-1. match url that doesn't contain asp, apsx, css, htm.html,jpg,

Q-2. match url that doesn't end with  asp, apsx, css, htm.html,jpg,

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the 'matches count' function, and make it match 0.

eg.
(matches all characters, then a dot, then anything that isnt aspx or css

```
^.*\.((aspx) | (css)){0}.*$
```

Edit, 
added ^ (start) and $ (end line chars)

Answer (score 0):

Q-1. This is better done using a normal string search, but if you insist on regex: `(.(?!asp|apsx|css|htm|html|jpg))*`.

Q-2. This is better done using a normal string search, but if you insist on regex: `.*(?<!asp|css|htm|jpg)(?<!aspx|html)$`.

Answer (score 0):

If your regular expression implementation does allow lookaround assertions, try these:

```
(?:(?!aspx?|css|html?|jpg).)*
.*$(?<!aspx?|css|html?|jpg)
```